# How to transpile on fly before running script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

Does anyone knows how to tackle following problem?
What is the best approach to resolve it?

I wanted to present the simplest example, but generally I would like to run node script that have some dependencies files that are not written in es5. This script takes argument from cli and perform some action (eg. change content of index.html file), here for simplicity we only console log some greeting.
Currently we would get an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Is there a way to somehow transpile on fly all file dependencies to es5 and run the script?

sample folder structure:

```
src/welcome.js
src/greeting.js
src/... // bunch of other files
package.json
```

greeting.js

```js
const name = process.argv[2];
export const sayHello = `Hello ${name}!`;
export const sayHi = `Hi ${name}!`;
```

welcome.js

```js
const { sayHello } = require('./greeting');

console.log(greeting, "Nice to meet you!");
```

in package.json

```json
"scripts": {
  "greet": "node src/welcome.js"
}
```

cli

```
npm run greet John
```

Comment: What version of `Node.js` are you using that you need to transpile your code to `ES5`? If you really need it, you can use something like `Babel` for `Node.js` - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-node.html

Comment: @goto1 Node still does not support ES6 module syntax out of the box